# How to save Oracle DDL in an automated fashion

Tags: sql, oracle, dbms-metadata

Oracle SQL Developer is able to export DDL through Tools -> Database Export... This works very well, but requires manual intervention.

I know of `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl()`, what I want to do is save the generated DDL in client machine which I use to connect to the Oracle DB using Oracle SQL Developer, this can be done manually.

But, I am looking for an automatic/scriptable way to export (save to local machine) DDL identical to what is exported through the manual way.

This is the SQL command I used to get DDL.

`select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('obJType','ObjName','Schema') from dual;`

How can I do that?

Comment: Iterate through USER_OBJECTS view and spool the result of your query to some file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spool and dbms_output.put_line to spool the results to your local machine.

You can see the link for an example [utl-file-saving-in-local-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882726/utl-file-saving-in-local-machine/60883518#60883518) spooling and tweak the same as per your requirement.